# Azure file sync in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I'm new with Xamarin development. I am using Azure bucket for file uploading in android mobile app.
 For test purpose i have build the console application that is uploading file on azure bucket successfully without any interrupt. 
 But when i'm trying to create access token from mobile development it get stuck and give me time out exception. If i create the token from console application and use that token for file uploading it give me another exception like" place holder not found". 
As i expected i need a mobile service for token generation, If you have any idea please share your opinions with me that would be very helpful. 
I'm also uploading Code that i'm using for android mobile development.

```
[Activity(Label = "WedAndroidApp", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    int count = 1;
    //string sas = "https://supplypark.blob.core.windows.net/transaction-images?sv=2015-04-05&sr=c&sig=iJ8CZOi%2BktarlmrbZVHK7rYLdMOnKCeBjuPqjrrkGnM%3D&se=2016-06-09T14%3A21%3A49Z&sp=rwdl";
    string sas_token = "https://supplypark.blob.core.windows.net/transaction-images?sv=2015-04-05&sr=c&sig=AeWe8rghAlKz77Xh%2BUM6S46AuUQzAaD2djqhaW9wdN8%3D&se=2016-06-09T14%3A21%3A49Z&sp=rwdl";
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

        //button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++); };
        button.Click += async delegate {
            button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++);
            await UseContainerSAS(sas_token);
        };
    }

    static async Task UseContainerSAS(string sas)
    {
        //Try performing container operations with the SAS provided.

        //Return a reference to the container using the SAS URI.
        CloudBlobContainer container = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri(sas));
        string date = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        try
        {
            //Write operation: write a new blob to the container.
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("tdi" + date + ".txt");

            string blobContent = "This blob was created with a shared access signature granting write permissions to the container. ";
            MemoryStream msWrite = new
            MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(blobContent));
            msWrite.Position = 0;
            using (msWrite)
            {
                await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(msWrite);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Write operation succeeded for SAS " + sas);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Write operation failed for SAS " + sas);
            Console.WriteLine("Additional error information: " + e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I am following this https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-xamarin-blob-storage/ for azure mobile development. But Azure storage dependencies are not getting download from neget package.

Comment: Hello Guys, i have solved the issue. If you are getting issue to install the dependencies please use Package Console manager to install the dependencies. Please follow this:- "Install-Package WindowsAzure.Storage -Version 4.4.1-preview -Pre"

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using Azure Mobile Apps, I would recommend that you use the built-in feature that accesses Azure Storage: [Connect to Azure Storage in your Xamarin.Forms app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-blob-storage/)

Otherwise, you should write code that creates a SAS token on your server, not your client. The storage master key should **never** be distributed with your client app, as it would be a big security risk. You should have the key in your server only, and it should send a SAS token to clients to scope access to a particular blob or container.

If you're using a .NET backend Mobile App/Mobile Service, then you should just move your SAS code to a custom API on the server. If you're using Node.js, you can follow this tutorial: [Work with shared access signatures in Node.js](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-nodejs-how-to-use-blob-storage/#work-with-shared-access-signatures).

If you don't have a Mobile App backend, then you can use Azure Functions to generate SAS tokens. Here is a sample: https://github.com/lindydonna/GetSasToken-function.

Note that Azure Mobile Service is deprecated, so you should be using Azure Mobile Apps instead.

Comment: Thank you, 
I was also thinking about to move the SAS generation code on server. due to security risk, But i generated the SAS token and pass as a parameter to UseContainerSAS(string sas) function , but it get stuck on file uploading. 
Should i also move the logic of file uploading on server?

Comment: No, the logic of file upload should still be on the client. I would step through it in a debugger to see what is happening. You can start with a console app to make it easier to debug. Also, if my answer was helpful, please accept it. :)

Comment: I tried the same thing in Console application it is working. I used the same code. Might be issue with Nuget dependencies that i am using for file uploading in android development.

Comment: Thank you, Code is working. I was using wrong dependencies. Now i followed this nuget package,
"Install-Package WindowsAzure.Storage -Version 4.4.1-preview -Pre ".
 i was trying to install WindowAzure.Storage from Nuget package, But now i installed using Package manager console.